# JPA Hibernate table doesnt exists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem that I've been struggling to solve but I'm not getting anywhere.

I'm using JPA Hibernate to create tables, but instead of creating the table, he shows me the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table ‘escola.tab_alunos’ doesn’t exist

Here's my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version=“2.0”>

    <persistence-unit name="banco" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>
    Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide
    </description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.halyph.sessiondemo.Event</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escola" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="0000" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And here's the class Aluno:

```
@Entity
@Table(name=“TAB_ALUNOS”)
@SequenceGenerator(name=“TAB_ALUNOS_PK”, sequenceName=“SEQ_ALUNOS_PK”, allocationSize=1)
public class Aluno {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="TAB_ALUNOS_PK")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=10, nullable=false)
    private String matricula;

    @Column(length=100, nullable=false)
    private String nome;

    @Column(length=9 ,nullable=false)
    private String sexo;

    @Column(name="DATA_NASCIMENTO", length=10, nullable=false)
    private String dataNascimento;

    @Column(length=30, columnDefinition="DEFAULT 'Ativo'")
    private String situacao;

    // ....
 }
```

Any idea on how can I solve this problem?

Just for the record, the first time I started the project, it worked just fine, but due to a mistake I've made, I had to drop the table, after that hibernate stopped creating the table and now I can't do anything

Answer (score 0):

**Modify**

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />`

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

The value="update" modifies the existing table while value="create" creates a table, but if the table already exists, it drops the table with the data and creates a table again.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />`

Refer here for all possible values of hbm2ddl.auto

[Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto possible values and what they do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

Answer (score 0):

The error shows up because your `persistance.xml` has been configured to update tables. During the first run, there are no tables that have been created, and thus nothing to update.

On the first run, set `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />` so that a table can be created from your pojo. Then, set it back to `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />` so that your tables can be *updated* instead of being *created* at each run

Answer (score 0):

Provide schema as well along with table name e.g.

```
@Table(name=“TAB_ALUNOS”, schema = "dbo")
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried changing it to:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

and i have also tried changing to:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
```

Neither one of those two worked.

Comment: The schema 'escola' is created. And the seq_alunos_pk is also created. The only thing that's not being created is the table tab_alunos

Comment: Try cleaning and restarting both your DBMS client and your web server, and dropping your schema. Everything looks fine.

Comment: I dropped the schema, restarted eclipse, restarted mysql service, even deleted the schema directly in the paste "mysql/data", the error remains.

Comment: Try changing xsi:schemalocation to "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0"> and closing the tag at the end of the document

Comment: EDIT your QUESTION with this info. This is not an ANSWER to the QUESTION!